# I want to calculate the limit: $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sin(n)$

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum

I am not entirely sure how to go about this one.

$\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sin(n)$

I am assuming $\sup$ means supremum, in which case since $\sin$ can only be in range of $<-1,1>$, supremum is $1$, which makes the limit $1$. Is this correct?

Edit: I misunderstood the task, corrected it, but that makes the above comment irrelevant

Comment: The expression is constant, so the value is $\sin n$. Did you mean to have $x$ as the limit variable?

Comment: The answer is $1$. $\sin n$ is dense in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sin(n)$? ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior))

Comment: As written, $\sin(n)$ is independent of the limit variable, so it's constant - the answer would be $\sin(n)$.

Comment: The result is $\sin n$, since you don't know what $n$ is.

Comment: @arkeet you are actually right, now I am completely lost, gotta go study what it means

Comment: @Mykybo, how about editing your question to state the problem correctly and formatting appropriately?

Comment: @user8960 yes, I just did so

Comment: Perhaps you should read the comments first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing $\sup \{ \sin n \mid n\in \mathbb N \} =1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63526/showing-sup-sin-n-mid-n-in-mathbb-n-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $\{e^{in}\}_{n\geq 0}$ [is dense in the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977450/density-of-ein-alpha/1977465#1977465), and the function $z\to \text{Im}(z)$ from the unit circle to the $[-1,1]$ interval is a continuous function, preserving density. It follows that $1$ is a limit point for the sequence $\{\sin n\}_{n\geq 0}$, so your $\limsup$ equals $\color{red}{\large 1}$.

Notice that *the range of the sine function is $[-1,1]$* is not enough to reach that conclusion.
For instance, the range of the functions $f(t)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ or $g(t)=\sin(\pi t)$ is also $[-1,1]$, but
$$ \limsup_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2n}{1+n^2}=\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\sin(\pi n)=\color{red}{0}.$$

Comment: Equivalently, $n-2 \pi \lceil {n \over 2 \pi} \rceil$ is dense in $[0,2 \pi]$.

Comment: @copper.hat: sure, that is also underlined in the linked proof.

Comment: That proof looks rather complicated for this case. Wouldn't it be enough to show that $\sup \sin(n)$ is always $1$, hence the limit is $1$?

Comment: @Mykybo: but $$\sup_{n}\sin(n)=1$$ still follows from density. What alternative (simpler) approach do you have in your mind?