# Giving an example of a sequence of complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

> Find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $B(0,1)$ such that $\sum(1-|a_n|)<\infty$ and every number $e^{i\theta}$ is a limit point of $\{a_n\}$.

This is an exercise from Conway that I am stuck at. What is an example of such a sequence? I thought of some spiral shaped sequence, but cannot give a rigorous construction of such a sequence. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Hint: If $r$ is irrational there are no $n$ and $m$ such that $r = \frac{n}{m}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Take a look at [Density of $e^{in \alpha}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977450/density-of-ein-alpha) and try with the spiral shaped sequence
$$a_n:=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)e^{in}\quad \text{for $n\geq 0$}.$$